# Can we set user defined field length in Cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

Can we set user defined field length in Cassandra database USING CQL.
I would like to validate input field in cassandra ex. age filed should not be more than 60 and less than 18.

Comment: Your question and your example don't seem to match up. "age between 18 and 60" isn't a limitation on the field length. Anyway, I'm not familiar with Cassandra specifically, but does [this](http://express-cassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators/) help? I just searched for "Cassandra field validation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is no such thing in cassandra**

You have to validate input from the application layer.